# how to use mouseup event in jquery range slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to call 'searchdata' function on mouseup event or slider stop.from this code slider call 'searchdata' function on sliding i also use slidestop event.

```
$( function() {
    $( "#age-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 18,
        max: 60,
        values: [$("#agehide1").val() , $("#agehide2").val()],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#age" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ] + "yrs  to " + ui.values[ 1 ]+" yrs " );
            $("#fromage").val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
            $("#toage").val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
            searchdata();
        }
    });
    $( "#age" ).val( "" + $( "#age-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " to " + $( "#age-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
        $("#fromage").val($("#age-range").slider( "values", 0 ));
        $("#toage").val($("#age-range").slider( "values",1 ));
} );
```

Comment: Please check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967435/jquery-ui-slider-call-function-on-mouseup-outside    and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546472/how-to-get-value-of-the-slider-when-touchend-or-mouseup-events-are-used

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$(function() {
    $("#age-range").slider({
        from: 0,
        to: 5,
        smooth: true,
        step: 10,
        round: 0,
        callback: function(val){
          console.log(val); 
        }   
    });
});
```